# DirectX error on Watch Dogs (game) in windows 8.1 and NVIDIA image preview on configuration is missing?

Tags: windows-8.1, nvidia-geforce, directx, direct3d, directx-11

i recently buyed a new laptop: HP Envy 15-J108LA.
i have been using it for 2 weeks now and been playing these 2 games withought ANY problem: watch dogs and Tera Rising.
then one day tera would give me errors and wont open, tried to see if i could play watch dogs and also got an error: "WATCH_DOGStm requires that your grafics hardware be compatible with DirectX 11, and have the directX 11 runtime installed"

What? it was working just fine yesterday!

from that i checked to see if directX was on using the directX diagnostic tool with dxdiag.exe:

**on display tab:**

DirectDraw: On

Direct 3D: On

AGP texture: On

**on the next tab:**

Direct Draw: On

Direct 3D: Off

AGP texture: On

later i opened the NVIDIA configuration and went to image adjustment settings and found that the 3D moving image preview was missing.

i dont know whats the problem or why this is happening all of a sudden, i suppose it is because of directx. anyway, if it helps, the last "change" my pc had was on 06/07/2014 (yesterday) where it updated with windows update. also, after all this, windows doesnt detect any problems or something. i **have directX 11 installed** by the way, and it shows that i still have it.

remember, it was working FINE before that day, so dont say its my procesor, hardware, etc, that is not the problem.

thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: The missing nvidia logo is strange, have you tried doing a clean install of your graphics drivers? If you didn't know, that means uninstalling without saved settings, reboot, install fresh drivers from nvidia website, reboot one last time and you should be good to go :)

Answer (score 1):

I would completely uninstall the graphics driver, reboot and install it again. It would be better to download the driver first but if you can't find it nvidia does have an auto detect feature to make it easy to install.

Answer (score 1):

It is not because your hardware WAS working fine, that it cannot be hardware related! Gaming requires serious cooling for your GPU and that is always a problem on a laptop. You could have thermal damage. If a reinstallation of the driver doesn't solve the problem, call HP for RMA.